# I want to observe the stage by stage image analysis in Tesseract ocr tools

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I would like to observe the step by step image analysis process that tesseract does to images that i pass to it. Is there any one who has done this before and can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ViewerDebugging) would help you, also there is more information on [this blog](http://rdaemons.blogspot.com/2012/06/tesseract-ocr-interactive-debugging.html), it is so simple.